# MonoDroid, no APK file generated in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, apk

I am using MonoDroid with VisualStudio 2010. When compiling in Release mode, the APK file is not generated (should be in BIN folder alongside compilation outputs).

It used to work like a charm. I am not able to point out what changed in my project configuration, monodroid installation or whatever.

I just have 3 warnings saying:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.  BCom.MAF.ViewModel
```

And one:

```
Assembly generation -- The version '1.0.0.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format  BCom.MAF.UI.Android
```

Could this be a (surprising) problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: just to be sure...have you tried clening your project?

Comment: Yes all cleaned. But this was my misunderstanding (cf answer). Thanks for the interest anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This my mistake: the APK file is only generated during a Publish/Start. Since I was only doing Build or Rebuild and not Start, even in Release mode, the APK is not generated.

In this [Xamarin Monodroid Documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Preparing_Package_for_Android_Marketplace), the *step 2* says to "test in release mode", to ensure all linking went right. It sounds a bit optionnal. Actually, it is mandatory to Start the app in Release mode to get the APK file.

This behavior can be changed by working a bit in the MSBuild tasks of the project.

Edit: There is a new "Deploy" Contextual Menu Entry now. All made easier :-)

Comment: The "Deploy" event also needs the emulator so it's quite the same as starting without debugger...